Start SIF at namespaced task
Is there a way to indicate a namespace with the SIF -To, -From, -Skip, and -Tasks parameters? For example, my install process failed at the IdentityServer SetLicense task. How do I restart from there?

Use an underscore, like this:
From = "IdentityServer_SetLicense"
